# Background size / position - cover the width, and a minimum offset from the top

Tags: css, background-image, background-position, background-size

I have a container with a background image.  I would like it to:

1. fill the width of the container at all times
2. if the height of the container gets bigger, the image should stick to the bottom and increase the gap at the top
3. if the height of the container is shorter than the image, it should maintain a 20px gap at the top, hiding the bottom of the image (as it overflows)
4. I do not know the height/width of the image in my CSS
5. The image should not skew (aspect ratio should be maintained)

It seems like what I need is `contain` on the width, but not height, but then I'm not sure how to do the minimum offset from the top.

See my attempts here:

```
background-size: 100% auto;
background-position: left 20px;

/* works when the height is shorter than the image
    ------------------
    |                |
    |                |
    |................| 
    |.              .|
    |.              .|
    |.              .|
    |.     .bg      .|
    |.              .|
    |.              .|
    |.              .|
    ------------------
     .              . <- this is clipped off, that is fine.
     ................
*/
/* 
    does not work when the height is larger than the image
    ------------------
    |                |
    |                |
    |................|
    |.              .|
    |.              .|
    |.              .|
    |.     .bg      .|
    |.              .|
    |.              .|
    |.              .|
    |.              .|
    |.              .|
    |................| <- I want this to be stuck to the bottom
    |                |
    |                |
    ------------------
*/
```

---

```
background-size: 100% auto;
background-position: left bottom;

/* works when the height is taller than the image

    ------------------
    |                |
    |                |
    |                |
    |................| 
    |.              .|
    |.              .|
    |.              .|
    |.     .bg      .|
    |.              .|
    |.              .|
    |.              .|
    |.              .|
    |................| <- stuck to the bottom, good!
    ------------------
*/
/* 
    does not work when the height is shorter than the image
     ................
     .              .
     .              .
     .              .
     .     .bg      .
     .              . <- This is clipped off
    ------------------
    |.              .|
    |.              .|
    |.              .|
    |................| 
    ------------------
*/
```

---

```
background-size: cover;
background-position: left 20px;

/* works when the width is wider than the image (scales it up)
    ------------------
    |                |
    |                |
    |................| 
    |.              .|
    |.              .|
    |.              .|
    |.     .bg      .|
    |.              .|
    |.              .|
    |.              .|
    ------------------
     .              . <- this is clipped off, that is fine.
     ................
*/
/* 
    does not work when the width is narrower than the image, and the height is taller
    ------------------
    |                |
    |                |
    |................|.....
    |.               |    . <- I do not want the width to overflow
    |.               |    .
    |.               |    .
    |.       .bg     |    .
    |.               |    .
    |.               |    .
    |.               |    .
    |.               |    .
    |.               |    .
    |................|..... 
    ------------------
*/
```

What I want:

```
/* if the container is shorter than the image
    ------------------
    |                |
    |                |
    |................| <- 20px offset from the top, full width of the container
    |.              .|
    |.              .|
    |.              .|
    |.     .bg      .|
    |.              .|
    |.              .|
    |.              .|
    ------------------
     .              . <- this is clipped off, that is fine.
     ................
*/
/* 
    if the container is larger than the image
    ------------------
    |                |
    |                |
    |                |
    |                |
    |................| <- full width of the container
    |.              .|
    |.              .|
    |.              .|
    |.     .bg      .|
    |.              .|
    |.              .|
    |.              .|
    |.              .|
    |.              .|
    |................| <- stuck to the bottom
    ------------------
*/
```

Snippet for testing:

```css
/* width/heights are for illustrative purposes - actual width-heights are unknown */
  
div {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: left 20px;
  
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;

  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
}

.taller {
  height: 500px;
}

.shorter {
  height: 100px;
}

.wider {
  width: 400px;
}

.narrower {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!-- this image size and the container size are variable depending on author input - these are included as test cases, but I do not know the sizes -->

<strong>Same Size</strong>
<div style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300');"></div>

<strong>Taller</strong>
<div class="taller" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300');"></div>

<strong>Wider</strong>
<div class="wider" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300');"></div>

<strong>Narrower</strong>
<div class="narrower" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300');"></div>

<strong>Shorter</strong>
<div class="shorter" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300');"></div>

<strong>Taller &amp; Wider</strong>
<div class="taller wider" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300');"></div>

<strong>Taller &amp; Narrower</strong>
<div class="taller narrower" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300');"></div>

<strong>Shorter &amp; Wider</strong>
<div class="shorter wider" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300');"></div>

<strong>Shorter &amp; Narrower</strong>
<div class="shorter narrower" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300');"></div>
```

Comment: Doesn't setting background width to 100% and position to bottom work? It wouldn't clip anything and the background will always fill the width 100% and it will be at the bottom always

Comment: No, then if the container is shorter, it clips off the top - i would want to maintain the offset from the top and have it clip off the bottom, as shown in my first example.

Comment: But wouldn't that happen eventually anyway if I keep reducing the height of my browser? Also, please add your current code to reproduce this issue

Comment: No, it would clip off the bottom - that is ok.  it will always show the top of the image if `top` is the `background-position` and that is what I want (that is what the offset is based on). I have added a illustration of this issue.

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: I did - its at the start of each comment

Comment: That's only the css, need markup as well, add enough to demonstrate the issue please

Comment: You can achieve this with an element positioned, say 20vh from the top of the page with a height of 80vh, and then just apply the bg width 100% and position bottom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible using just CSS, but you need to change a little bit your markup, by adding container div. I made an container resizable to simplify testing of this solution.

```css
.container {
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;

  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding-top: 20px; 
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.image {
  margin-top: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 150%;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300');"></div>
</div>
```

How it works:

`.container` has:

- `display: flex`, it is important to allow a "margin magic" to work,
- `justify-content: flex-end` to push the div with image to bottom;
- `padding-top: 20px` to always keep the empty space you wanted

`.image` has:

- `width: 100%` to fill space horizontaly,
- `height: 0` and `padding-top: 150%` to keep the image proportions ratio,
- `background-repeat: no-repeat` so image is used just once, and with `contain` it fill div horizontally,
- `margin-top: auto` with `display: flex` of parent allows vertical move of div, but constrained by parent padding,

**EDIT** in response to OP comment

It seems, that you still can use this method even if you don't know the image width and height, and therefore cannot calculate ratio - if you modify it a little bit. It actually make it even simpler

```css
.container {
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;

  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding-top: 20px; 
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.image {
  margin-top: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="image" src='https://picsum.photos/200/300'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the best answer so far, *except* in my premise, I do not know the height/width of the image (so not the ratio either).

Comment: True, so please check out my edit for the answer. This time I think I got it right ... BTW. nice question, I learn a little bit by answering it, so thank you for that! ;)

Answer (score 1):

If the container is taller the img will stretch, if it's wider it will stretch.
adding the 20px on the top will cut 20px from the bottom.

```
background-size:100% 100%;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

Comment: This *stretches* the image if it is smaller than the container, and messes up the image aspect ratio.

Comment: "I am attempting to position a background image so that it is always filling (but not overflowing) the width of the container"
I suppose what i suggested matches your demands, then again if the image doesn't stretch it won't fill the container as you wanted, am i missing something here ?

Comment: stretching is ok, the aspect ratio skewing is not

Comment: Then how in the world do you expect this img to fill the container?

Comment: My goal is not to fill it height-wise, only width-wise.  Please see the last illustration I provided

Comment: Okay i'm confused, Correct me if i'm wrong, you want it fill the width at all times, then if the height of the container get bigger the img should stick to the bottom and increase the gap at the top, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I updated the question to more clearly define my goals.

Comment: Question, how is that gap at top will be applied ?

Comment: I was using `20px` in the `background-position` to achieve that, but I am open to suggestions since that attempt doesn't seem to do what I want.  The answer I have accepted leveraged `padding`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170245/discussion-between-zohirsalak-cena-and-allicarn).

Comment: I've been trying to get to work using the background of the container as requested, I got to work to some extent, in the case when the width gets bigger than the height  the background stretchs with the width and it loses its aspect ratio, but other than that it works fine, I don't think what you want can be achieved using the background, your best bet is to use the accepted answer way with some absolutely poisoning to put it as background, that was a nice brain twister though :)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing what markup you have, I created this example you can refer to. The key is to have the div positioned xxx from the top so it will never cover up the top space.

You can see how it resizes using the full page snippet or https://jsfiddle.net/xen6hszn/

```css
body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: grey;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  background: url(https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/_89716241_thinkstockphotos-523060154.jpg) left bottom no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  height: 80vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div>

</div>
```

Comment: This is clipping the top of the image off - I want the top of the image always visible, it's the bottom that can be clipped.  I see where you're going though, it gives me an idea!

Comment: Then use contain for the background size, your image I suppose will be big enough to cover whatever width you have. The one in the example is not that big of an image

Comment: This does not clip it off the bottom, it scales the whole thing if you have a shorter viewport.

Comment: You will probably need javascript to get exactly what you want